# Change host name in endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

If I have a webservice, I am on creating it on server side, I have the endpoint, let's say, localhost:port/etc.
Can you please tell me how can I configure the host name, on server side, for example, to be etc...:port in Tomcat with CXF?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you **deployed** your service in one server, the `etc...` in `etc...:port` cannot be changed, unless you deploy it in another server so that the client can request to 2 servers.

When you write the service to deploy on the server, the `port` and `etc...` can be changed using `Endpoint.publish()`.

Answer (score 0):

For JaxWS client endpoints, when you call a `getPort` method on a `Service`, you can cast the result as a `BindingProvider` instance.

You can then set the endpoint URL using something like :

```
((BindingProvider) port)
    .getRequestContext().put(
         BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
         "yourURL:yourPort");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for reading my question, but I am interested in doing this change on server side.

Comment: OK... then it depends on how you deploy CXF. Are you using the standard CXF servlet with a Spring configruation file and the jaxws namespace ?

Comment: I didn't choose the path, but this is my plan. Or maybe to add the host name in the server config...?